# 3.1 Details We noticed that your app contains irrelevant platform information. Referencing third-party platforms in your app or its

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore-approval

I submitted my app to AppStore(https://itunesconnect.apple.com) it is new version App,  but My app rejected and they left this message but I don't know, what I have to fix... It wasn't clear on message what to fix.

3.1 Details We noticed that your app contains irrelevant platform information. Referencing third-party platforms in your app or its

Any one can help me with that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you talk about Android, Windows, Blackberry, etc in either text or screenshots and someone in the review team catches it, you will have to remove the info.

Comment: thanks a lot, i dont know why apple they dont write very clear, i have on my website the icon of android,  in my app i linked a page of my website to my app probably they saw the Android Icon.

Comment: Only Apple can say for certain of course but yes, that sounds like it may be the culprit.

Comment: in my case, my app icon contains an image of android phone lol

Answer (score 5):

I also faced this issue, Let me tell you story.

1. I had a background image with a person holding a non iOS cell phone, (I guess its a blackberry). Appstore rejected because of it,
2. App description in itunesconnect, I linked www.mywebsite.com
   and they App store rejected because if it.
3. In App description I mentioned "purchase license from us", then again the rejected because of it.

Answer (score 2):

> In my case, this happened because the word "Android" was in
>   my App description.

While filling out the 'description' for my iOs app, I simply pasted the same description I set for the Android version (on Google play store). Since I did not format, the word "Android" managed to slip in and Apple rejected my metadata.

*There was no need to upload a new build or anything. I simply removed the "Android" word and re-uploaded, and yes, it got accepted!*

I hope this helps someone out there.

Merry coding!

Answer (score 1):

Hi In my case it was the boarding(tutorial) screens. I have used android phones in those design. Once after I changed it to iOS phones, my app was accepted.