# App includes references to Android in the metadata

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, app-store

I have built an app using react-native and I wanted to release my app on the app store so I built an ipa using Xcode and submitted it to the app store.
2 days later apple rejects the app saying

> Guideline 2.3.10 - Performance - Accurate Metadata
>
> We noticed that your app or its metadata includes irrelevant third-party platform information.
>
> Specifically, your app includes references to Android in the metadata.
>
> Referencing third-party platforms in your app or its metadata is not permitted on the App Store unless there is specific interactive functionality.

How exactly do I solve this issue? I'm pretty sure that when building a bundle for iOS react native automatically only packages common and ios related code.

Comment: Hey friend, check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58013247/5670752):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guideline 2.3.10 reads as "Make sure your app is focused on the iOS, Mac, Apple TV or Apple Watch experience, and don’t include names, icons, or imagery of other mobile platforms in your app or metadata, unless there is specific, approved interactive functionality." as mentioned in the below link
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#accurate-metadata

you can refer to the below links to solve the issue.
https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808528-iOS-Troubleshooting-Metadata-Rejected-in-App-Store-Review-Status

But you are right that when building the bundle the react native will only package common and iOS related code. But you can check in the code whether you have added any method names with android specific details. If in case you have android related explanations in comments section (// or /* comments*/), it will be ignored.

Comment: I have platform specific code like this `if(Platform.OS ==='android') {//some code} and does that cause an issue?

Comment: This chunk of code is in JS i think and if so it shouldn’t create any problem. I also do understand that you cannot share the whole codebase to check.

Comment: check if you have android related images in your assets by chance.

Comment: Were you able to find the solution to the issue?

Comment: Yes turns out that i had the word android in the description.

Comment: Oh! good that you found the issue. All the best with your app.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple App Store doesn't check your code.
Meta Data means the data which you provide to publish your app on App Store.

Check if you have accidentally put "android" word in that anywhere.

In my case i have added "android" word in app description

Answer (score 1):

They refused my app because I put an image that mentioned available on "Google play "